# Next lander/rover mission

Tags: probe, rovers, landing, lander, moons

Beyond Mars and 67P, what is the next most viable mission for probe landing? How far are we from sending one to the Jupiter or Saturn system?

Comment: Future NASA missions are listed here: http://i.imgur.com/2qgg1BQ.jpg

Comment: Next one is probably ISRO's Chandrayaan-2 planned for 2015 and sending a lander and a rover to the Moon. Then China's Chang'e 5 in 2017 with a sample return also to the Moon, ESA's ExoMars rover to Mars in 2018, NASA's Mars 2020 rover mission,... others I know of are even more tentative. There's however a few upcoming sample return missions, such as JAXA's Hayabusa 2 that launches in 11 days towards asteroid 1999 JU3, NASA's OSIRIS-REx in 2016 to asteroid 101955 Bennu,...

Comment: @ TidalWave Great, I forgot that Hayabusa 2 mission is sample-return.

Comment: Poorly. Not very well to the mind of most. More is better.

Comment: What do you mean by *viable*?  Feasible?  Our own moon is certainly most feasible.  Or is that not what you're asking?

Comment: @ gerrit Landing on celestial bodies that we haven't explored in this way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next lander beyond Mars will be the Osiris-Rex lander, expected to launch in 2018, which will land on an asteroid. The next mission to Saturn or Jupiter will likely be the [Europa Lander](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/van-kane/20160105-nasa-europa-lander.html), which is tentatively planned for 2022.